# DropDownList in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Suppose I have a Gridview having some rows. i have two columns containing dropdown lists.
My question is to find the RowIndex of a GridView when SelectedIndexChanged Event of GridView occurs of one dropdown list such that i can apply the functionality of another dropdown list in a same row(Read the comment too).
Sample code is listed here:

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I want the row index so that i can apply the functionality in same row
    // If this doesn't work, any alternative ?
}


protected void func()
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"]
    for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
        DropdownList d1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("dropdown1");
        DropdownList d2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("dropdown2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the GridView row this way:

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropdown1 = sender as DropDownList;
    GridViewRow row = dropdown1.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    // Do something with row or with row.RowIndex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `EventArgs` to `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` and you'll be able to get the row from `e`

So your method becomes:

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int row = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: it didnt work ! Error on line DataGridViewCellEventArgs